# Reentry permit needed or DACA changed?

Tags: resident-permit

My mother in law recently came (home country is Iraq) here on an IR5 (daughter bringing her mother to the US).  She was immediately given a green card.  This was back in early June.  She will be leaving us to return back to her home country in November but she stated that she probably wont be back for another 2 years.

According to what she received in her paperwork if she is out of the US longer than 1 year she needs to fill out form I-131: https://www.uscis.gov/i-131 to apply for a re-entry permit because she will be out of the US for longer than one year.

I filled it out the other day but wanted to check where to mail it when I encountered a new message at the top of this page.  It reads:

> DACA Has Changed!
>
> We are no longer accepting initial requests for DACA, but we will
>   adjudicate initial requests for DACA accepted by Sept. 5, 2017. We
>   will no longer approve advance parole requests associated with DACA.
>   We are only adjudicating DACA renewal requests received by Oct. 5,
>   2017, from current beneficiaries whose benefits will expire between
>   Sept. 5, 2017 and March 5, 2018. Read the 2017 DACA announcement

I'm not sure I understand the ramifications for her.  She is not a refugee nor is she applying for parole travel document.  She is simply applying for a reentry permit.  On the form itself (page 2 of 5) for Part 2 (Application Type) she has the box for 1a checked which reads:

**I am a permanent resident or conditional resident of the united states, and I am applying for a reentry permit.**

So according to this announcement should I still file this application or have things changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That message is not relevant for her. The Form I-131 is used to apply for 3 types of documents: Advance Parole, Re-entry Permit, and Refugee Travel Document. DACA beneficiaries used to be able to apply for Advance Parole (there are other categories of people who can apply for Advance Parole, not just DACA), but that is no longer allowed due to a recent change in policy. The message is just saying not to apply for DACA-based Advance Parole anymore. It does not apply to Re-entry Permits (which is what your mother-in-law is applying for) or Refugee Travel Documents, or to non-DACA-based Advance Paroles.

Comment: Wow thanks - so am I filling out the right document for what she needs.  She will be leaving the US in november and cannot return for more than a year later (possibly two years).